# Zend Framework And Parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there any way how to view all sent parameters if I do not know their name?

For example, I sent these parameters:

- id = 1 (GET)
- name = 'John' (GET)
- surname = 'Smith' (GET)

**Example**

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
echo $request->getParam[0]; // Will output 1
echo $request->getParam[1]; // Will output 'John'
echo $request->getParam[2]; // Will output 'Smith'
```

Thank you!

*(I'm not a native English speaker.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the getParams() method to get a combination of all the request params:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

foreach($params as $key => $value) {
    // Do whatever you want.
}
```

There are also getQuery() and getPost() methods.

Comment: exactly what's on my mind but more clearer. Mine was var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams();
)

Comment: @Hanseh - if the OP wants to print out the keys and values of `$_GET` parameters the ZF way, using `$request->getParams()` will also give him the controller, action and module in addition (which he may not want, judging from the specificity of the question).

Comment: @karim79 - my mistake. I was just reiterating the idea that getParams() function is available and he can get his needed variable by manipulating it. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
print_r($request->getQuery()); // returns the entire $_GET array
print_r($request->getQuery("foo")); // retrieve a single member of the $_GET array
```

So to grab the parameter names and values programmatically, for example, in a simple loop:

```
foreach($request->getQuery() as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key is: " . $key . " and value is: " . $value . '<br />';
}
```

Check out the [API docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.10/) for `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`.